# Load data for Mask RCNN

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to train Mask-RCNN on my own dataset. I already have the segmented images (ground truths) of leaves which look something like the image below:

[image: rcnn train image]

How can I load the dataset for training Mask RCNN?

Answer (score 0):

Since Mask RCNN is pre-trained on COCO dataset,you need to train it with these images. For that purpose you have to label them and train it. Since a mask is involved use a tool such as VGG annotator to do the necessary annotation and labelling, it will generate a json file depending on your classes. Later based on your requirement you have to run the .py files for your classes, train and then generate it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert this to TFrecords for the MASK RCNN model to be able to read the image and its annotations. Please refer this medium article 'https://medium.com/@vijendra1125/custom-mask-rcnn-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api-101149ce0765'

Answer (score 0):

You can use coco annotations ( [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/akTwelve/c7039506130be7c0ad340e9e862b78d9) ) to annotate your dataset and then just run it like you use coco dataset.

Also you can check this code : https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/shapes/train_shapes.ipynb